# Pyserial can read data from arduino in command line, but python file cannot

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I'm reading serial data from arduino with mpu6050 using pyserial. It runs normally in command line, but reads nothing in a python file.

This is for Arduino UNO, pyserial3.4, baudrate 115200, Window10.

```
#in command line
>>> ser = serial.Serial("com3", 115200, timeout=1)
>>> ser.write(b"1")     #write a chatacter to begin
>>> ser.readline()
b'ypr\t-84.35\t7.81\t-1.14\r\n'

# in a python file
ser = serial.Serial("com3", 115200, timeout = 1)   
ser.write(b"1")
#time.sleep(1)          #makes no difference
data = ser.readline()   #timeout and read nothing
```

Comment: did you print the `data`?

Comment: @vaku yes, it's  b''

Comment: Try this one `while True: print(ser.readline())`

Comment: in file you have to use `print()` to see data on screen. Python's shell (command line) prints results from all commands without `print()` to make life easier when you test commands.

Comment: @vaku I ran it for 1min, it just kept printing b''

Comment: Did you see output in the serial monitor of arduino IDE...

Comment: @furas I use vscode with python extension and can watch variable in visualization.

Comment: @vaku yes, it works well too.

Comment: Did you cross-check COM ports if yes then try to reconnect the Arduino board in another port...and close all other services that are reading that port like serial monitor or your idle....

Answer (score 0):

I solve it use:

```
data = ser.readline()
while data == b'':
    ser.write(b"1")
    data = ser.readline()
```

It seems that a single writing doesn't work.